# What does single parentheses mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I see look at [Changing a number between arbitrary bases, Math Gems answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111150/changing-a-number-between-arbitrary-bases) and see such annotation : 1⋅6+2=10)6=60)+1)=61)6=446)+3=451

What does 10)6 mean? What single ")" mean? Mathematics teacher not taught us 
about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me they are closing parentheses.  He is trying to show the steps in evaluating $\ ((1\cdot 6+{\color{red}2})\:6+{\color{blue}1})\:6 + {\color{orange}3}$ in base $8$. He starts with the inner parenthesis and states $1\cdot 6+{\color{red}2}=10$  The next step is to multiply this $10$ by $6$, but he has not shown the opening parenthesis. I would say it is not standard notation, but seems to me a useful way to show what is going on.

Comment: This may help. Here’s the first expression, completely parenthesized: $$\color{orange}(\color{green}(\color{red}(\color{blue}((1\cdot6)+2)\cdot6\color{blue})+1\color{red})\cdot6\color{green})+3\color{orange})\;.$$ Here’s what you get if you insert the partial evaluations from left to right: $$\color{orange}(\color{green}(\color{red}(\color{blue}((1\cdot6+2=10)\cdot6=60 \color{blue})+1=61\color{red})\cdot6=446\color{green})+3=451\color{orange})\;.$$ Now remove the outermost parentheses and all of the left parentheses, and you have Math Gems’ abbreviated expression.