# Weird way of converting to a higher base

Tags: algorithms, intuition, number-systems

I used to think that there is only one to convert to a higher base ie: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111158/407302

If we want to convert $(1200)_3$ to $(45)_{10}$ we do the following:

$1\cdot 3^3 + 2\cdot 3^2 + 0 + 0 = 27 + 18 = 45$

But I have found a weird way of by multiplying only a single power of the "incoming base" from the right.

It goes in the following way:

1. Start with $[0,0]$
2. Add 1 to it -> $[0,1]$ $1$ is from the left hand digit of $1200$
3. Multiply with 3 (base) and add 2 (ie. 2 from $1200$, second digit) we get $[0,5]$
4. Multiply with 3 (base) and add 0 (ie. 0 from $1200$, third digit) we get $[1,5]$
5. Multiply with 3 (base) and add 0 (ie. 0 from $1200$, last digit) we get $[4,5]$

Here is the same calculation but in base-16(hex):

```
[0,0] + 1 = [0,1]
[0,1] X 3 + 2 = [0,5]
[0,5] X 3 + 0 = [0,F]
[0,F] X 3 + 0 = [2,D] -> 2D
```

*Disclaimer: I have arbitrarily taken the construct $[0,0]$ represent the result because this method is taken from the Java library(BigInteger) which uses arrays to convert really large integers to an internal representation of base $2^{32}$. You can try it with an arbitrary length of zeroes too.*

I have no idea why this method works.

**Is this methods only valid for when converting to a base higher than the base of the given number ?**

I have some intuition about why the "normal" method works : *each place in the number from left to right denotes how many times a the base has "overflown", hence we add a digit to the left and reset the digit to the right.*

But this I am unable to figure out the arithmetic.

**How does this method work ? Why does it work ?**

Am I only one impressed by this ? Am I missing something really basic ?

Comment: This is a pretty common way to evaluate polynomials $\sum_{i=0}^n a_nx^n,$ which is what you are doing. It takes fewer multiplications.

Comment: Note what happened to your initial $1$: it gets multiplied by $3$ three times, equaling $3^3$; and so forth.

Comment: In a computer, this isn't really changing a base - it is doing the computations in base $2$ and then, outside the algorithm, computing the base $10$ representation.

Comment: In any event, the polynomial evaluation algorithm is often covered when teaching ways you can improve algorithms. It requires $n$ multiplications and $n$ additions, which is an improvement from the naive algorithm, which requires $2n$ multiplications and $n$ additions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Could you please elaborate what you mean by "doing computations 
 in base 2" ? It still uses decimal arithmetic to do this, correct ? What do you mean by computing base 10 outside the algorithm ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Could you point me to where this is used specifically for base conversions ? I could only find something called Horner's Method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method and shift and add https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add

Comment: @ng.newbie As I said, this is polynomial evaluation. The fact that base conversion uses polym9mial evaluation is trivially true. Not sure where to find a reference, nor why you'd need one.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you elaborate on how the polynomial method takes fewer multiplications ? I understand that it is the same as "classic" method, but doesn't that then mean the number of multiplications are same ?

Comment: @ng.newbie I'm sure you can work that out yourself.